# Convert two lists into keys and values of new map, respectively

Tags: java, list, dictionary, data-structures, apache-commons

The code to do this is exactly easy:

```
Map<K, V> listsToMap(List<K> keys, List<V> values) {
    // check preconditions - sizes
    Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
    for ( int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
        map.put(keys.get(i), values.get(i));
    }
}
```

My question is: does this exist in one of the most common Java libraries? That would be the standard library, including Java 7 or Java 8, Apache Commons, or Guava. I'm asking here because I've thus far failed to find it on a Google search, and therefore, adding an SO question with the best keywords I've used will help the next person with the same problem.

Comment: I've not seen this library, and my very simplistic guess is that it won't exist because the operation of converting two lists to a map is not necessarily well defined. If you have variations in length, there can be multiple reasonable approaches (mapping keys to null values, throwing a mismatch exception, etc..). But, that's just my guess.

Comment: @Kon "multiple reasonable approaches" might be the reason this is hard to get in general. I just found Guava.toUniqueIndex which almost works and takes a stance on it by throwing an error.

Comment: Guava lists this as a specifically rejected method [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/IdeaGraveyard#create_a_map_from_an_Iterable<Pair>_,_Iterable<Map.Entr).

Answer (score 0):

There is exactly one function in these libraries that imperfectly works, and it is in Guava's [`Maps.uniqueIndex`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#uniqueIndex(java.util.Iterator,%20com.google.common.base.Function)). You would expect it in [`MapUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MapUtils.html) in Apache commons.

Note this function

- doesn't actually support two lists, so it doesn't have to worry about different lengthed-lists
- throws an exception if duplicate keys are attempted

Any function that does this work would have to take a stance on those two conditions. Furthermore if two lists are supported the function would have to take a stance on different sized lists, either throwing an exception or losing values, etc.

Furthermore there is the question of what a "duplicate key" means. In particular if (k,v) is inserted twice is it okay to swallow?

So any one function would have to answer all of these questions. Therefore you are actually looking for a `KeyValueListsToMapFunctionBuilder.`

Declarative programming in Java is in its infancy. If it were mature, exactly a "key value lists to map function builder" would exist, and if it were *really* mature, it would have a concise name and interface. However most of Java is still imperative, and by programming this function out yourself - as in the OP's code - you make all of these choices imperatively, in about as many lines as you would have to declaratively. So, in conclusion

- there is one decent function that works in best-case scenario and makes decisions for what to do on bad input
- anything more general would have complex configuration
- the "declarative" Java ecosystem is not terribly mature, so you have to implement the complex configuration imperatively yourself, i.e., just write the darn code.